# React Native App Stuck On Splash Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, react-native

I am trying to learn how to build a react-native module. I followed [a tutorial](http://blog.tylerbuchea.com/how-to-create-a-react-native-ios-native-module/) and I am getting stuck on the splash screen. I also get this error when I try to run my app:
`Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`
[image]

I have not modified any of the code in `index.ios.js` but I have created and two files:

#### GifMaker.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"

@interface GifMaker : NSObject

@end
```

#### GifMaker.m

```
#import "GifMaker.h"
#import "React/RCTLog.h"

@implementation GifMaker
// This RCT (React) "macro" exposes the current module to JavaScript
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

// We must explicitly expose methods otherwise JavaScript can't access anything
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(get)
{
  RCTLogInfo(@"Hello There!");
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I used [react-native-create-library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-create-library) to create the .h and .m files and then just copied those into my project.